# font awesome icons do not line up correctly next to text in materialize collection

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, materialize

I want to use some of the icons from font awesome rather than google's material icons, however the font awesome icons do not line up correctly in a link collection.

```
<div class="col s12 m4 l3 xl2">
  <div class="collection with-header white">
    <h6 class="collection-header"><i class=" material-icons left">insert_link</i>Links</h6>
    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <a href="#!" class="collection-item orange-text valign-wrapper"><i class="fab fa-github fa-2x left"></i>Font Awesome</a>
    <!-- Material Icon -->
    <a href="#!" class="collection-item orange-text"><i class="material-icons left">insert_chart</i>Material Icons</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The material icon leaves a nice gap to the text, but the font awesome icon doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Could you add css as well?

Comment: Yeah, I just realised I could add my own css to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give some width to the icons. And as I see you don't need to use `.left` class to the icons.

Simply use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle;`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.collection i {
  width: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="col s12 m4 l3 xl2">
  <div class="collection with-header white">
    <h6 class="collection-header"><i class=" material-icons">insert_link</i>Links</h6>
    <a href="#!" class="collection-item orange-text valign-wrapper"><i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>Font Awesome</a>
    <a href="#!" class="collection-item orange-text"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i>Material Icons</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding CSS fixed the issue by putting a margin next to the font-awesome icons

```
 .fa-2x {
    margin-right: 15px;
 }
```